# linking an image with a rating

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently developing a web app where i want users to rate an image. I am using Polldaddy.com as the source of the rating widget.

```
<div id="scriptwrapper">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var slides = [{
      img : 'slidepagepic01.jpg',
     desc : 'Cotswolds, England'
```

---

this coding is from seattleclouds.com and thats where i am currently building the app. The code is for an image slider. I would like to link the different images in the slider to it's own unique rating widget. Problem is I'm not sure where to insert the coding for the rating widget. I've been at this for almost 2 weeks. Please assist

Answer (score 0):

How about using a database for that.. 
so like if 5=5stars and so on and so forth

You do not even really need to use any js just like a db driven photo gallery..